# Making "java -jar OSBuddy.jar" an icon I can execute on my desktop?

Tags: java, xfce, .desktop, jar

Title says it all. I'm really really new with Linux stuff. Using Xfce/Crouton/Ubuntu etc.

If you can be as specific as possible, or linking me to a guide that breaks everything down step by step that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Write a shell script such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar OSBuddy.jar
```

save that to a file called OSBuddy.sh (caps in unix file names bug me but thats just me) and make sure to mark the permissions as executable.

```
chmod +x OSBuddy.sh
```

Now when you call it make sure to use:

```
./OSBuddy.sh
```

if you are in the same directory otherwise put it in the full path (if you call it from the command line).

To make an icon for it:
Right click on your shell script in the file browser. Create link. Then drag and dropped the link to desktop.

Or run the program if its a GUI, and then on the launcher, right click and there should be a command to "Lock to Launcher".